# ASP.NET Core + React API Call with MSAL Azure AD Auth

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I am attempting to make an API call from js to a .net controller using Azure AD authentication via MSAL.

My flow starts with logging into my React application using MSAL. Once logged in, I grab a token.

```
    const { instance, accounts, inProgress } = useMsal();
    const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState<string | null>(null);

    const name = accounts[0] && accounts[0].name;

    function RequestAccessToken() {
        const request = {
            ...loginRequest,
            account: accounts[0]
        };

        // Silently acquires an access token which is then attached to a request for Microsoft Graph data
        instance.acquireTokenSilent(request).then((response) => {
            setAccessToken(response.accessToken);
        }).catch((e) => {
            instance.acquireTokenPopup(request).then((response) => {
                setAccessToken(response.accessToken);
            });
        });
    }
```

i then attempt to embed this token into my js fetch call

```
    const headers = new Headers();
    const bearer = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;

    headers.append("Authorization", bearer);
    //headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json")

    const options: RequestInit = {
        method: "GET",
        headers: headers
    };

    const response = await fetch('/kpiData', options);
```

`Program.cs` of the asp.net backend has

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});
```

my network response

[image: network response]

why is my token invalid? configuring `Program.cs` correctly seems quite difficult.

Update:

appsettings.json

```
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com",
    "ClientId": "<Client ID from Azure App Registration>",
    "TenantId": "common",
    "Audience": "Client ID from Azure App Registration>"
  }
```

authConfig.ts

```
export const msalConfig: Configuration = {
    auth: {
        clientId: "<Client ID from Azure App Registration>",
        authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<Tenant ID>",
        redirectUri: "https://localhost:44493"
    },
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: "sessionStorage", // This configures where your cache will be stored
        storeAuthStateInCookie: false, // Set this to "true" if you are having issues on IE11 or Edge
    }
};

// Add scopes here for ID token to be used at Microsoft identity platform endpoints.
export const loginRequest: RedirectRequest = {
    scopes: ["api://<Client ID>/User.Read"]
};
```

Comment: then I think you may decode the access token you generated to check if the scope claim had correct value

Comment: @TinyWang thanks a lot for your help. i got it working based on your sample code as well as setting the scopes in my loginRequest as well as Azure

Comment: Does your token has the required permission? Please [`check the token here`](https://jwt.io/)